# Angle issue here. Can't make a sensible diagram out of this.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

What I'm basically asking you to do is:

> P, Q and R are three points on level ground. The bearing of R from P is $135^\circ$, $\angle PQR=55^\circ$ and $\angle PRQ=48^\circ$.

> Draw $\triangle PQR$ such that the bearing of

> 1. P from R is $315^\circ$
> 2. Q from R is $003^\circ$ or $267^\circ$
> 3. P from Q is $220^\circ$

while the actual question was:

> P, Q and R are three points on level ground. Given that the bearing of R from P is $135^\circ$, $\angle PQR=55^\circ$ and $\angle PRQ=48^\circ$, find the bearing of

> 1. P from R
> 2. Q from R
> 3. P from Q

(I got the answers from the answer key. This question is from a grade-8 math textbook.)

Comment: May I suggest using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

[image: point bearing exercise]Start with a line segment $RQ$, and make $\angle QRP=48^o$ and $\angle RQP=55^0$. This determines point $P$, and that $\angle RPQ=77^o$. Draw $PS$ such that $\angle RPS=135^0$. So $PS$ is the line from which the bearing of $R$ from $P$ is taken.

To find the bearing of $P$ from $R$ draw $RT$ parallel to $PS$. Hence $\angle TRP$, the supplement to $\angle RPS$, $=45^o$, and the bearing of $P$ from $R$, taken counter-clockwise, is $360^o-45^o=315^o$.

The bearing of $Q$ from $R$, taken from $RT$, is $48^o-45^o=3^o$.

Finally, to get the bearing of $P$ from $Q$, draw $QU$ parallel to $PS$. Since $\angle RPS=135^o$, and $\angle RPQ=77^o$, then $\angle SPQ=135^o-77^o=58^o$, and its supplement $\angle PQU=122^o$. Therefore, the bearing of $P$ from $Q$ is $360^o-122^o=238^o$. However, this last does not agree with the answer key. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: Exactly. What has gone wrong?